# Email not sending to customers in magento

Tags: php, magento

i'm working in magento,i'm not able to send all type email to customers. when any customer generate any order then magento show message that your order message has been sent,But customers are not getting.

Comment: Please give me some response. i lost my too much time in this task. So please provide me any solution.

Comment: is your server is configured with mail server also is cron jobs working ? did you set the System > sales emails > mail ids...

Comment: please tell me how to check that our server is configured with mail server? cron jobs are working , and also enabled the emails from admin panel..

Comment: go to backend > system > configuration > sales > sales emails > Send Order Email Copy To  = > enter your email address.

also install this extension to check cron jobs : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

if you want to send email without help of server, than you can use this : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Comment: i also created a testmail.php on server , it perfectly send emails..

Comment: please provide the name of second extension , which send emails without help of smtp server..

Comment: this extension require smtp server's configuration details..

Comment: yes, you can follow from screenshots provided in extension link.

Comment: Hey ! i'm not getting email. i done all process.

Comment: did you installed aoe scheduler extension and checked cron is working or not ?

Comment: yes.. i installed aoe scheduler and cron is working...

Comment: on clicking on sales-> order ->send email, flags the message "email is sent "
but email is not going to customer

Comment: is other emails like `pASSWORD RESET` MAILS ARE WORKING ?

Comment: no, any emails are not going ?

Comment: which payment methods are you using ?

Comment: cash on delivery , pay u money checkout , these 2 payment methods i am using

Comment: for both emails are not going, did you check spam folder ?

Comment: yes sir, i checked that too, but emails are not there..

Comment: Any one have any solution.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: i'm using 1.8.0 version of magento.

Comment: when i log " $this->recipients " in the lib\Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail.php function then it prints "  =?utf-8?B?cmF2aSBzaGFua2FyIHNoYXJtYQ==?= <arvind.sharma@vksoftwares.com>
 "   instead of arvind.sharma@vksoftwares.com  , i want to know that what is this " =?utf-8?B?cmF2aSBzaGFua2FyIHNoYXJtYQ==?=  " in recipients , please clarify the issue..

Comment: hii.. Now i'm able to send all types email to customers.